# Invoke method of specific members basetype

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection

I've got a problem invoking with these classes:

```
public class Container 
{
    IARepo a = new ARepo();
    IBRepo b = new BRepo();
    ICRepo c = new CRepo();
}

public class ARepo:Repo<ABase>, IARepo 
{
}

public interface IARepo: IRepo<ABase> 
{
}

public interface IRepo<T> 
{
    GetAll();
}

public class Repo<T> : IRepo<T> 
{
    GetAll();
}
```

I have to iterate over a, b and c to find a specific member of the container and call GetAll() via reflections on it.

What i do at the moment is:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(container).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.Name.Equals(NAME OF REPOSITORY))
    {
        //Access GetAll() for the specified property
    }
}
```

Using `MethodInfo` I can't access `GetAll()` as it is declared in a base type of the member.

Could you enlighten me on how to do it and why sour solution works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the overload of GetProperties that allows you to specify the BindingFlags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_

Comment: 1. In the code you posted here you are using fields not properties. 2. `FieldInfo` aswell as `PropertInfo` instances provide a `GetValue` method that gives you back the value of the property/field of a paticular container instance. 3. Call `GetAll()` on that value.

Comment: You have provided code what is not working and full of errors. This is a pitty because other members want to help you but need to do a lot of effort to fix your code. I cannot help you now because I am getting confused what your problem is. e.g. all your properties are private so you will not include them in your for loop, however I do not think that is your real problem. Please take some effort to give code what is working